# How to set include_directories from a CMakeLists.txt file?

Tags: cmake

I seem to be having trouble setting the include path (`-I`) using the `include_directories()` command in CMake. My project directory is as follows:

```
Root
| - CMakeLists.txt
| - libs
| - | - CMakeLists.txt
| - | - inc
| - | - | - // lib specific includes
| - | - src
| - | - | - // lib specific sources
| - proj1
| - | - CMakeLists.txt
| - | - inc
| - | - | - // proj1 specific includes
| - | - src
| - | - | - // proj1 specific sources
```

The root `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like so:

```
project(ROOT)
add_subdirectory(libs)
add_subdirectory(proj1)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file under `libs`:

```
project(lib)
add_library(lib STATIC ${lib_hdrs} ${lib_srcs}) // for conciseness, omitted set()
```

And lastly, the `CMakeLists.txt` file under `proj1`:

```
project(proj1)

include_directories("${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/inc") # <- problem line?

add_executable(proj1 ${proj1_srcs})
target_link_libraries(proj1 lib)
```

The goal is to create the library from the source and header files in libs, then link against the executable generated under proj1. Proj1 has some files that `#include` stuff in libs include, so I need to add the directories to be used with `-I`. Based on the documentation, that's what `include_directories()` is supposed to do. However despite explicitly setting that and following it with a debug `message(${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})`, the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` variable is an empty string, and no directories are specified for the include path, so my compilation of proj1 fails.

I've also attempted removing the quotes around `${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc` to see if that helped but no luck.

Comment: Typo?  You have `include_directories("${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/inc")` but `lib` should be `libs`.  And invoking the CMake function `include_directories` won't actually populate a variable named `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.

Comment: Apologies, that's just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`include_directories()` populates a directory property called `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_dir:INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES

Note that CMake 2.8.11 learned the `target_include_directories` command, which populates the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property.
 http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_include_directories

Note also that you can encode the fact that 'to compile against the headers of the `lib` target, the include directory `lib/inc` is needed' into the `lib` target itself by using `target_include_directories` with the `PUBLIC` keyword.

```
add_library(lib STATIC ${lib_hdrs} ${lib_srcs}) # Why do you list the headers?
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC "${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/inc")
```

Note also I am assuming you don't install the `lib` library for others to use. In that case you would need to specify different header directories for the build location and for the installed location.

```
target_include_directories(lib
  PUBLIC
    # Headers used from source/build location:
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/inc>"
    # Headers used from installed location:
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>"     
)
```

Anyway, that's only important if you are installing `lib` for others to use.

After the `target_include_directories(lib ...)` above you don't need the other `include_directories()` call. The `lib` target 'tells' proj1 the include directories it needs to use.

See also [`target_compile_defintions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) and [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html).

Comment: So that's what PUBLIC is for. The documentation wasn't quite clear on it.

Comment: JAB: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-specification-and-usage-requirements

Comment: `target_include_directories(<your_lib> PUBLIC <dir1_with_path> <dir2_path>)` what I was looking for. This helps specifying "includes for the specified target only".