# cMake for large projects

Tags: cmake

I currently have a very large file structure that I would like to port over to cMake, but unfortunately I am have a really difficult time finding examples similar to the file structure I am currently working with.

(the *_*_.c/h means any file name)

```
Project
   Target
        <*.s19/*.elf goes here>
   Component1
        src
            file.c
            file.h
            ____.c
            ____.h
        cfg
            ____.c
            ____.h
        out
            <*.o goes here>
        tmp
            <*.d goes here>
   Component2
        src
            file.c
            file.h
            ____.c
            ____.h
        cfg
            ____.c
            ____.h
        out
            <*.o goes here>
        tmp
            <*.d goes here>
   Component3
        src
            file.c
            file.h
            ____.c
            ____.h
        cfg
            ____.c
            ____.h
        out
            <*.o goes here>
        tmp
            <*.d goes here>
```

Also, how would I tell it to look for includes in a certain component, like for example I want files in component 1 to only look for #includes in Component2. Also, how would I tell it to only compile in a certain list of files, for example within src, I may only want it to compile in file1.c, but not file2.c

Comment: I'd _strongly_ suggest not trying to mix binary and source directories like this. One of CMake's strongest features is the ability to do [out-of-source builds](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#What_is_an_.22out-of-source.22_build.3F), which can save you lots of maintenance headaches, especially when dealing with large projects.

Answer (score 0):

How to use different include directories in different components (with help of @ruslo and @steveire):

2. In the main CMakeLists.txt add components in the right order:

   ```
   add_subdirectory(Component1)
   add_subdirectory(Component2)
   ```
3. In the Component1/CMakeLists.txt add a property to the generated library::

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

   ...

   add_library(Component1 ${Component1_SOURCES})
   target_include_directories(Component1 INTERFACE
     "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>"
     "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>"
     ... other required includes
   )
   ```
4. In the Component2/CMakeLists.txt use `target_include_directories` for the Component2:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

   ...

   add_executable(Component2 ${Component2_SOURCES})
   target_link_libraries(Component2 Component1)
   ```

Regarding exact list of files to be compiled. Frankly speaking I don't see any problem in this area. Simply specify them explicitly in the `add_executable` or `add_library` directives:

```
add_binary(Component1Binary test1.c test2.c test5.c)
```

But I should mention that traditionally CMake uses slightly different layout for compiled artifacts. It places either compiled artifacts right within the source directory, or you may create a totally separated directory and it will put *all* compiled artifacts there, completely reproducing your project structure. Take a look:

```
 MyProject/
     CMakeLists.txt <- the top-level CMakeLists.txt. It may simply `add_subdirectory()`s (for each of its `Components`) and configure project-wide settings
     Component1/
         CMakeLists.txt <- this is intented to build artifact(s) for Component1
         src1-1.c
         src1-1.h
         ...
     Component2/
         CMakeLists.txt <- this is intented to build artifact(s) for Component2
         src2-1.c
         src2-1.h
         ...
```

now you may create an empty directory with an arbitrary name (say, `build.release`) *anywhere* in your filesystem (usually somewhere within MyProject but not necessary), then `cd` to that directory and call cmake like this:

```
 cmake [cmake flags like -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release and others] path/to/the/MyProject
```

CMake then creates all required Makefile-s and other build artifacts in this directory and you may call `make` (or `ninja` if you've chosen to use `ninja` instead of `make`) and all build artifacts would reside in that directory, reproducing the original structure of `MyProject`:

```
build.release/
     Component1/
         src1-1.o
         ...
         Component1.a
     Component2/
         src2-1.o
         ...
         Component2Exe
```

etc

More on `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` stuff is in [docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_include_directories), [How to set include_directories from a CMakeLists.txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460707/how-to-set-include-directories-from-a-cmakelists-txt-file) etc. The feature is relatively new and I still not sure that I did everything absolutely correctly (the test example does compile though).

Comment: You don't need to manage include_directories like that. Encode them into the component1 target, not into a variable. Then target_link_libraries automatically consumes them. Simply set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

Comment: Thank you! It seems I've missed these changes in CMake development (I've just checked, it's available since 2.8.8-2.8.11). Although I couldn't get "automatic" behaviour with just `target_link_libraries`, there's a solution with two `target_include_directories`. I will update the answer and please re-check my solution

Comment: You should be able to remove the target_include_directories in step 3. See http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-next/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html. File a bug if you have a non-working testcase.

Comment: Well, it seems that CMake-2.8.12.1 installed on my computer doesn't mind against INTERFACE, but you're right, PUBLIC is perfectly enough for this case. Also, with PUBLIC it's possible not to specify `target_include_directories` in the Component2. So I'm updating the answer, hopefully, finally.

Comment: Then I don't understand the whole idea. With PUBLIC I do receive the expected result, at least in the simple test application and CMake-2.8.12.1. Or maybe I miss something?