# Link up src/ with CMake as library #include'd with some `libname/` prefix

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, include-path

For my research project I am setting up a project (`coom`) to benchmark a set of algorithms on a data structure. For unit testing I settled on *Bandit*, which leaves me with a project structure that looks as follows:

```
+ root
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-+ external/
| \-- bandit/
|-+ src/
| |-- CMakeLists.txt
| |-- node.cpp
| \-- node.h 
\-+ test/
  |-- CMakeLists.txt
  |-- test.cpp
  \-- test_node.cpp
```

From my experience with other languages, this seems to me a standard project structure? The `test/` folder contains unit tests for the logic in `src/` and no dependencies are intermixed with the source and test code, but are instead in `external/`.

The testing files I **want** to look as follows (with irrelevant parts removed)

```
// test/test.cpp
#include <bandit/bandit.h>
(...)

#include "test_node.cpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  (...)
}
```

```
// test/test_node.cpp
#include <coom/node.h>
(...)
```

But my problem is, that when I try to compile with `cmake ..` and the subsequent `Makefile`, they are unable to find the source code in `src/` where I get the compiler error:

```
fatal error: coom/node.h: No such file or directory.
```

I would expect the `test/CMakeLists.txt` should look somewhat like the following:

```
# test/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable (test_unit test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_unit coom)
```

I cannot figure out how to setup the `CMakeLists.txt` and `src/CMakeLists.txt` to ensure I get the desired outcome above. Currently they look as follows:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project (coom VERSION 0.1)

# ============================================================================ #
# Dependencies
(...)

# ============================================================================ #
# COOM project
add_subdirectory (src)
add_subdirectory (test)
```

```
# src/CMakeLists.txt
# ============================================================================ #
# Link up files for the library
set(HEADERS
  node.h
)

set(SOURCES
  node.cpp
)

add_library(coom ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
```

I can see from other projects, that it is possible to link the `src/` directory with some `libname/` prefix, but I cannot discern from their `CMakeLists.txt` files what I am doing wrong. I have looked at writing a `coom.pc.in` file and providing an `install`-target, and tried to `set_target_properties` with either `FOLDER coom` or `PREFIX coom`, but neither worked. I can hack an `include_directory(../src)` into the `test/CMakeLists.txt` to be able to include the file via an `#include <node.cpp>`, but that screams I'm doing something inherently wrong.

I'm at this point very much pulling my hairs out, and the CMake documentation is of very little help to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `coom` target has no include directories defined. You can define the include directories to use for this target (with [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)), and *propagate* these include directories so they are visible to the consuming `test_unit` target (by using `PUBLIC`):

```
# src/CMakeLists.txt
# ============================================================================ #
# Link up files for the library
set(HEADERS
  node.h
)

set(SOURCES
  node.cpp
)

add_library(coom ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(coom PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Furthermore, the file path to the `node.h` header is `coom/src/node.h`, not `coom/node.h`. But, because you now have `coom/src` as an public include directory, you can use the following to include the `node.h` header in your test file:

```
#include <node.h>
```

Comment: With regards to the `coom/src/node.h` and `coom/node.h` I see I made my question unclear by using the same name twice. The latter was the intention with the current file structure. Maybe that is just not possible?

The `target_include_directories` works (and is prettier than all I've tried at this point), but is it best practice? Maybe I did something wrong in with the folder structure?

Comment: No, I don't think CMake or the compilers support this "aliasing" a prefix (for lack of a better term), unless you do something hacky with sym-linking the directory. `coom/node.h` simply isn't a valid path to the header file, so the compiler will not know how to find it. There have been similar questions asked here already about this, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38879819/3987854). You could instead use the top-level CMake directory in `target_include_directories()`, then include the header using `src/node.h`. Perhaps, you could rename the `src` directory to `coom`?

Comment: @SteffanSølvsten All that said, the use of `target_include_directories()` is standard CMake practice for adding include directories to the compilation of a specific target. I added a link to the documentation in my response.

Comment: It explains why the TPIE dependency have their src/ folder named tpie/. Thanks for the reference to the other question; irritating that my searches about "prefix" didn't bring it up. Thanks for the thorough answer.