# Path mismatch when including libraries with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-modules

I am trying to include two libraries into my project to use them.
I'm using CMake with CLion.

The two libraries are: https://github.com/herumi/bls and https://github.com/herumi/mcl

I got the following project setup:

[image]

This is the main CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(blsbenchmark)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(blsbenchmark ${SOURCE_FILES})

include(FindPkgConfig)
find_package(bls REQUIRED)
include_directories(${BLS_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${BLS_LIBRARY})

find_package(mcl REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MCL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MCL_LIBRARY})
```

The `Findbls.cmake`:

```
set(FIND_BLS_PATHS
        /opt/bls)

find_path(BLS_INCLUDE_DIR bls.h
        PATH_SUFFIXES include
        PATHS ${FIND_BLS_PATHS})

find_library(BLS_LIBRARY
        NAMES bls384_256
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib
        PATHS ${FIND_BLS_PATHS})
```

The `Findmcl.cmake`:

```
set(FIND_MCL_PATHS
        /opt/mcl)

find_path(MCL_INCLUDE_DIR bn_c384_256.h, bn.h
        PATH_SUFFIXES include
        PATHS ${FIND_MCL_PATHS})

find_library(MCL_LIBRARY
        NAMES mclbn384_256
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib
        PATHS ${FIND_MCL_PATHS})
```

This setup allows me to include the files of the library very nicely in my project:

[image]

However, problems arise because, as you can see, I can link the library files directly in my main (bn.h and bls.h) without their prefixes (bls/bls.h or mcl/bn.h).

Thus, when trying to build this I get a:

```
fatal error: mcl/bn.h: No such file or directory
   11 | #include <mcl/bn.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

because the library itself requires the prefix "mcl/bn.h" path.

[image]

Thus, the question is how I can include these two libraries (mcl and bls) into my project with the prefix in the path such that this also is compatible with the two libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38879819/3987854), you have to provide a **different** path to the `include_directories()` command. In your case, you can provide the *parent* directory to those found in your custom Find Modules.

For example, for the `mcl` repository, the header is located here `mcl/include/mcl/bn.h`. This is how you've defined the include directories now:

```
mcl/include/mcl/      bn.h
^                     ^
include directory     #include header
```

To achieve what you want, this is how you *should* split this up:

```
mcl/include/          mcl/bn.h
^                     ^
include directory     #include header
```

So, use the *parent* directory to the one actually containing the header file.

```
set(FIND_MCL_PATHS
        /opt/mcl)

# Find the path containing the header.
find_path(MCL_HEADER_DIR bn_c384_256.h, bn.h
        PATH_SUFFIXES include
        PATHS ${FIND_MCL_PATHS})

# If path with header file was found, set MCL_INCLUDE_DIR to the parent directory.
if(MCL_HEADER_DIR)
    # Grab the parent directory to MCL_HEADER_DIR.
    get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR ${MCL_HEADER_DIR} DIRECTORY)
    set(MCL_INCLUDE_DIR ${PARENT_DIR} CACHE PATH "MCL include directory" FORCE)
endif()

find_library(MCL_LIBRARY
        NAMES mclbn384_256
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib
        PATHS ${FIND_MCL_PATHS})
```

Now, you should be able to compile using the following include in your code:

```
#include <mcl/bn.h>
```

Comment: Sorry that I did not include this in the post above, but the files were already in:
/opt/mcl/include/bn.h and /opt/bls/include/bls.h. Adjusting it to the code you've pasted above, now gives me a loading error in my main.cpp (can't find neither mcl/bn.h nor bn.h)

Comment: @user2524707 My response is based on the path provided in the repository. The path `/opt/mcl/include/bn.h` actually doesn't even have an `mcl` prefix directly before the `bn.h` header, so using `#include <mcl/bn.h>` is not possible. You could instead prefix with `include`, by doing `#include <include/bn.h>`.

Comment: Ah yes, with the code you provided, it is now include/bn.h, however, this again has the same problem as before (since the library needs it in mcl/bn.h)

Comment: Using your code and putting a "mcl" folder instead of a "include" folder actually solved it for me. Thanks a lot. If you could edit this in your answer I can accept it.

Comment: @user2524707 Unless you physically move the header files into a directory called `mcl` (so they could be located in `/opt/mcl/include/mcl`, for example), then including them via `#include <mcl/bn.h>` would not be possible.