# CMake #include path relative to project root

Tags: c++, cmake

Here is a simplified version of my C++/CMake project's layout:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
│
├── project_name/
│   ├── source_1.hpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
│
├── tests/
│   ├── test_1.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
```

And here are `CMakeLists.txt`:

- Root directory:

  ```
  add_subdirectory(project_name)
  add_subdirectory(tests)
  ```
- `project_name` directory:

  ```
  add_library(main_library INTERFACE)
  target_include_directories(main_library INTERFACE .)
  ```
- `tests` directory:

  ```
  add_executable(test_1 test_1.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(test_1 PRIVATE main_library)
  ```

So in `test_1.cpp` I want to include `source_1.hpp`.
Currently, I have to write `#include "../project_name/source_1.hpp"`.

Is there a way to use a path that would be relative to the project's root directory for such includes, i.e. `#include "project_name/source_1.hpp`?

Comment: Not your point, but `"project_name/source_1.hpp"` is not an absolute path because it's still interpreted relative to the current directory. An absolute path starts with `/` (on Linux at least).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant an absolute path from project's root directory.

Comment: "that would be relative to the project's root directory" - just call command `include_directories` or `target_include_directories` and pass project's root directory to it. Not sure what is a problem.

Comment: "I meant an absolute path from project's root directory" - Once again, *absolute* path is the one started with `/`. All other paths are *relative*. So what do you want is "path relative to the project's root directory". (and path you use currently - `#include "../project_name/source_1.hpp"` - is a "path relative to the current directory"). Please, use **correct terminology** when possible. Many things becomes very confusing when use words in the wrong context.

Comment: @Tsyvarev fixed the question, thank you. About `target_include_directories` – is it okay to include the whole project when all I need is a `project_name` directory?

Comment: "is it okay to include the whole project when all I need is a `project_name` directory?" - Generally, it is up to you what is OK or not in your project. But with current files structure you have no other way for make `#include "project_name/source_1.hpp` to work. But would I have the same purpose, I would think about moving `source_1.hpp` header into `project_name/include/project_name/source_1.hpp` and making `project_name/include/` as *include directory*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Header files with prefix in CMake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879819/header-files-with-prefix-in-cmake-project).  As commented earlier, you can use `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` in the `include_directories()` command to add the project's root directory to the include directories, if you want to **prefix** your `#include` directives.